# Compile error in standard library when compiling code

Tags: c++, xcode, stdmap, std-pair, stdset

I've done quite some java coding already, but I'm totally new to c++ and have no idea what's going on with my code right now. This code gives me a compile error in the map standard library. It says: `Cannot increment value of type ' std::_1::pari<int, int>'`, and is happening in `map`, `insert(_InputIterator __f, _InputIterator __l)` if that's of any relevance.

I know the stackoverflow community generally doesn't like solving other peoples homework, but I think I made a genuine attempt at implementing this and besides that I'm very curious as to what's going on.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> location;

std::set<location> neighbours(location loc, std::set<std::pair<location, location>> labyrinth, int& size) {
    std::set<location> neighbours;
    location locFmin = location(loc.first - 1, loc.second);
    location locSmin = location(loc.first, loc.second - 1);
    location locFplus = location(loc.first + 1, loc.second);
    location locSplus = location(loc.first, loc.second + 1);

    if (loc.first - 1 >= 0 && labyrinth.find(std::pair<location, location>(loc, locFmin)) == labyrinth.end()) {
        neighbours.insert(locFmin);
    }
    if (loc.second - 1 >= 0 && labyrinth.find(std::pair<location, location>(loc, locSmin)) == labyrinth.end()) {
        neighbours.insert(locSmin);
    }
    if (loc.first + 1 < size && labyrinth.find(std::pair<location, location>(loc, locFplus)) == labyrinth.end()) {
        neighbours.insert(locFplus);
    }
    if (loc.second + 1 < size && labyrinth.find(std::pair<location, location>(loc, locSplus)) == labyrinth.end()) {
        neighbours.insert(locSplus);
    }

    return neighbours;
}

int Labyrinth(std::set<std::pair<location, location>> labyrinth, int size) {
    std::map<location, location> forest;
    std::set<location> level;
    std::set<location> known;

    known.insert(location(0,0));
    level.insert(location(0,0));

    while (!level.empty()) {
        std::set<location> nextLevel;
        for (location loc: level) {
            for (location neighbour: neighbours(loc, labyrinth, size)) {
                if (known.find(neighbour) != known.end()) {
                    known.insert(neighbour);
                    forest.insert(neighbour, loc);
                    nextLevel.insert(neighbour);
                }
            }
        }
        level = nextLevel;
    }

    std::list<location> path;
    location walk = location(size - 1, size - 1);
    path.push_front(walk);
    while (walk != location(0, 0)) {
        walk = forest[walk];
        path.push_front(walk);
    }

    int answ = path.size();

    return answ;
}
```

It's an algorithm that should perform a breadth-first search trough a square maze of size `size` with of course size * size `location(x, y)` objects.
the incoming list `labyrinth` defines the walls of the maze one can't go trough. Eventually the function should return the number of nodes contained in the shortest path from (0, 0) to (size - 1, size - 1).

this is a simple test for the algorithm

```
std::set<std::pair<location, location> > labyrinth;
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(0, 0), location(1, 0)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(0, 1), location(1, 1)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(0, 2), location(0, 3)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(1, 1), location(1, 2)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(1, 2), location(2, 2)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(2, 3), location(3, 3)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(2, 2), location(3, 2)));
    labyrinth.insert(std::pair<location, location>(location(2, 1), location(3, 1)));

    int labAnswer = Labyrinth(labyrinth, 4);
    std::cout << labAnswer << std::endl;
    if (labAnswer == 13)
    {
        std::cout << "Correct" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect" << std::endl;
    }
```

Before anyone starts to come up with better ideas to solve this problem. I got the idea for the bfs code from a graph bfs java implementation from a book on algorithms. I'm not interested in solving this puzzle more efficiently, there'll always be better ways to do something. I'd like to know what is going on with my code and possibly what c++ aspect I'm missing here.

Comment: post the compile error... you might not be able to interpret it but some of us can.

Comment: Ah yea, had not thought of that. Edited the question to include error and part it gives the error on.

Comment: full compiler output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using std::map correctly with insert,

the line

```
forest.insert(neighbour, loc);
```

should be

```
forest[neighbor] = loc;
```

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

Check your #include headers, you will need to

```
#include <map>
```

Also, if you add `using namespace std;` then you can skip adding `std::` to every declaration.